Upgrade node js runtume version in aws lambda
Hello I have a lambda function which is using node js 12 as runtime, I need to modify it to use nodejs20x, I guess instead of update the YAML file and deploy it again, I can use aws cli, such as aws chime create-app-instance , aws chime create-app-instance-user, aws chime create-app-instance-admin which are doing the same what my lambda function made.
My doubt is, I can get ride of the get rid of the lambda deploy, how can I guarantee that the new app instance created is using nodejs20x as runtime? maybe I am misunderstanding concepts, but I need just to update the lambda runtime version to 20 and I don't want to deploy a new lambda function, I think is more clean to do the same using aws cli, any ideas? Thanks!
